# Google Calendar won't remove a task already removed from Remember the Milk

Tags: google-calendar, integration, remember-the-milk

I have a Remember The Milk Pro account. I decided that I want to see my tasks in my calendar, so I imported the RTM Events iCal into Google Calendar. This functioned well for a long time.

Recently, I got a long, tedious task of low-ish priority and decided that I will sit at it for one hour each day until it is completed. So I created a daily recurring task in Remember The Milk, without an end date (because I didn't know how many days it will take to finish). I worked a bit every day, and finally completed it. Then I deleted it from Remember The Milk, selecting the "stop repeating" option.

The task is not displayed in RTM any longer. But it still appears in Google Calendar, once a day, for all days in the future. I deleted it 3-4 days ago, so it should have had enough time to sync the change. Moreover, I have changed (added, completed, postponed) other tasks in RTM since I deleted this one, and the changes have been updated correctly in Google Calendar.

Is there something I did wrong, or is this a bug? If this is a bug, is there a workaround? I wanted to remove the RTM iCal subscription from my Google Calendar, wait a bit, and add it back, but couldn't find an option for that in the settings. And, if this is really a bug without a workaround, where should I seek support, at RTM or at Google?

Answer (score 1):

Try what you've proposed: delete the calendar by going to Settings -> Calendars and unsubscribe / delete. Then re-add it to GCalendar. I'd seek support with RTM (they're the ones pushing events to that calendar, plus you have a PRO account).